# How can I get user input in a python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I have a python discord bot and I need it to get user input after a command, how can I do this? I am new to python and making discord bots. Here is my code:

```py
import discord, datetime, time
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import date, datetime

prefix = "!!"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True)

times_used = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"I am ready to go - {client.user.name}")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{client.command_prefix}python_help. This bot is made by drakeerv."))

@client.command(name="ping")
async def _ping(ctx):
  global times_used
  await ctx.send(f"Ping: {client.latency}")
  times_used = times_used + 1

@client.command(name="time")
async def _time(ctx):
  global times_used
  from datetime import date, datetime

  now = datetime.now()

  if (now.strftime("%H") <= "12"):
    am_pm = "AM"
  else:
    am_pm = "PM"

  datetime = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M")

  await ctx.send("Current Time:" + ' '  + datetime + ' ' + am_pm)
  times_used = times_used + 1

@client.command(name="times_used")
async def _used(ctx):
  global times_used
  await ctx.send(f"Times used since last reboot:" + ' ' + str(times_used))
  times_used = times_used + 1

@client.command(name="command") #THIS LINE
async def _command(ctx):
  global times_used
  await ctx.send(f"y or n")
  times_used = times_used + 1

@client.command(name="python_help")
async def _python_help(ctx):
  global times_used
  msg = '\r\n'.join(["!!help: returns all of the commands and what they do.",
                     "!!time: returns the current time.",
                     "!!ping: returns the ping to the server."])
  await ctx.send(msg)
  times_used = times_used + 1



client.run("token")
```

I am using python version 3.8.3. I have already looked at other posts but they did not answer my question or gave me errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll be wanting to use `Client.wait_for()`:

```py
@client.command(name="command")
async def _command(ctx):
    global times_used
    await ctx.send(f"y or n")

    # This will make sure that the response will only be registered if the following
    # conditions are met:
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and \
        msg.content.lower() in ["y", "n"]

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    if msg.content.lower() == "y":
        await ctx.send("You said yes!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You said no!")

    times_used = times_used + 1
```

And with a timeout:

```py
import asyncio # To get the exception

@client.command(...)
async def _command(ctx):
    # code
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30) # 30 seconds to reply
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, you didn't reply in time!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) - More examples in here
- [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
- [`asyncio.TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError)

Comment: `msg = await client.wait_for(...` puts their `message` into a variable. You can view the contents with `msg.content`. ^ I edited the answer with an example

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot!

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)

Comment: Making a bot right now. Trying to add a hangman game to it. This helped so much.

Comment: Almost done with my hangman game. Such a success... Thank you times infinity. :)

Answer (score 1):

**With this you can make something like this**

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
    computer = random.randint(1, 10)
    await ctx.send('Guess my number')

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and int(msg.content) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    if int(msg.content) == computer:
        await ctx.send("Correct")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Nope it was {computer}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few days on trying to figure that out, and the only thing that was simple for me was storing the message.content into a list and using it later.

```
some_list = []
    user_message = message.content.split()
    some_list.append(user_message)
```

and since I am using commands I wanted to remove that '!' and get the raw message

```
        for i  in some_list:
        del i[0]# delete's command tag
```